# Unable to build a project on WSL2 using Visual Studio (VS) 2019 with OneAPI compilers

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, intel-oneapi

I am using VS 2019 with WSL2 to build a cross-platform app. I use OneAPI tools. I could successfully compile on Windows, but not on WSL2. The reason is VS does not recognize 'mpiifort' as it doesn't read the default bash environment. How to solve this.
Is there a way to 'source /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh' from VS or using CMakeSettings.json